# Improvised way to use split function

Tags: perl

I am using split function to extract the a string from given line.

**exp :**

```
\abc\Logs\PostBootLogs\05-27-2014_17-05-51\UILogs_05-27-2014_17-05-52.txt 
\abc\Logs\PostBootLogs\01-10-1970_20-33-22\01-10-1970_21-18-26\UILogs_01-10-1970_21-18-27.txt
```

**In the above exp we need to capture string which is there between PostBootLogs and UILogs_01-10-1970_21-18-27.txt**

Code :

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $data = '\abc\Logs\PostBootLogs\05-27-2014_17-05-51\UILogs_05-27-2014_17-05-52.txt';
my $test1 = '\abc\Logs\PostBootLogs\01-10-1970_20-33-22\01-10-1970_21-18-26\UILogs_01-10-1970_21-18-27.txt';
my @values = split('UILogs'(split('PostBootLogs', $data)));
my @values1 = split('UILogs', $values[1]);

print "$values1[0]\n\n";
print "$test1\n\n";

my @values_1= split('PostBootLogs', $test1);
my @values1_1 = split('UILogs', $values_1[1]);

print $values1_1[0];


exit 0;
```

is there any better way to do this thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regex to capture between `PostBootLogs\` and `\UILogs`

```
my ($captured) = $data =~ /PostBootLogs\\ (.+?) \\UILogs/x;
```

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions make this sort of thing much easier.

```
$data =~ m/PostBootLogs(.*?)UILogs/ or die "Misformatted data";
my $timestamps = $1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Creative use of splits.  As has been demonstrated, the easiest method to do this is to use a regex.

However, if you want to see how to use splits to more cleanly accomplish this observe the following:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @data = qw(
    \abc\Logs\PostBootLogs\05-27-2014_17-05-51\UILogs_05-27-2014_17-05-52.txt
    \abc\Logs\PostBootLogs\01-10-1970_20-33-22\01-10-1970_21-18-26\UILogs_01-10-1970_21-18-27.txt
    );

print "splits: \n";
for (@data) {
    my ($vol, @path) = split /\\/;
    my $subdir = join '\\', @path[3..$#path-1];
    print $subdir, "\n";
}

print "regex: \n";
for (@data) {
    if (/PostBootLogs\\(.*)\\UILogs/) {
        print "$1\n";
    } else {
        warn "Data format not recognized: $_";
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
splits:
05-27-2014_17-05-51
01-10-1970_20-33-22\01-10-1970_21-18-26
regex:
05-27-2014_17-05-51
01-10-1970_20-33-22\01-10-1970_21-18-26
```